# Overwrite an id of a parent element of a Jinja template

Tags: flask, jinja2

My `base.html` template has a navbar.

```
{% block navbar %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
      ...
    </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

I use it in all child templates like this:

```
{% block navbar %}
    {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```

However, in one template I need it to be displayed slightly differently. Thus, I would like to override `id` attribute of my parent navbar from `"mainNav"` to `"mainNavInverse"`.

Is it possible to do? If yes, how can one do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve it like this:

```
{% block navbar %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav{% block navbarextendid %}{% endblock %}">
      ...
    </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

And then use it like this:

```
{% block navbarextendid %}Inverse{% endblock %}
{% block navbar %}
    {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```